# CFG for $n_b = n_a + n_c$

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, context-free-grammar

I am trying to figure out the CFG of the given language.

The language is:

```
(number of b) = (number of a) + (number of c)
```

eg: bbac, bbbabcac ...

When I only consider the (number of b) = (number of a). I find a CFG something like this.

```
S -> aSbS | bSaS | €
```

But I cannot upgrade this CFG to the triple equality.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think its not contextfree.

Comment: So do you think that can we prove it with pumping lemma with selecting a word like $a^pb^{2p}c^p$ ? @Wuestenfux

Comment: @searil: in the description of the language, $a$ and $c$ are identical. You could take any sentence in the language, change an $a$ to a $c$ (or vice versa) and the sentence would still be in the language. (That's a hint.)

Comment: @rici I fixed the examples. You are right bacb is valid example.

Comment: Can't you just add two more productions with $c$ in place of $a$?  Why doesn't that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

\begin{align}
S &\gets XSbS \mid bSXS \mid \varepsilon\\
X &\gets a \mid c
\end{align}